# ctrl key not working when using certain application

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, java, minecraft

my ctrl key will not work when using Minecraft. It works when I use the Minecraft launcher, but when I start the java application "Minecraft" it will not work anymore. I have tried multiple versions (modded and vanilla), so maybe it has to do with the ".minecraft" folder, but I can't find the solution. When I take a look in the Minecraft settings there is nothing abnormal, so ctrl is assigned to the appropriate actions. Also I can't ctrl+A and such when in a text field.

Thanks in advance!

edit: I deleted the ".minecraft" folder and let it generate new. Still the Problem remains.